# my code in visual studio 2005 & 2008 & 2010 is work but in borland c++ 5.02 is not work,and have error

Tags: c++, borland-c++

My code in visual studio 2005 & 2008 & 2010 works but in Borland c++ 5.02 is does not.

The error is:

```
Info :Compiling C:\Program Files\BORLAND C++ 5.02\BIN\noname00.cpp
Error:  noname00.cpp(85,26):Qualifier 'amaliat' is not a class or namespace name
Error:  noname00.cpp(85,28):Function call missing )
Warn :  noname00.cpp(87,2):Parameter 'mab' is never used
Warn :  noname00.cpp(87,2):Parameter 'date' is never used
Error:  noname00.cpp(91,26):Qualifier 'amaliat' is not a class or namespace name
Error:  noname00.cpp(91,28):Function call missing )
Warn :  noname00.cpp(93,2):Parameter 'mab' is never used
Warn :  noname00.cpp(93,2):Parameter 'date' is never used
Error:  noname00.cpp(102,24):Qualifier 'amaliat' is not a class or namespace name
Error:  noname00.cpp(102,17):If statement missing )
Error:  noname00.cpp(115,2):Identifier 'chapeKol' cannot have a type qualifier
Error:  noname00.cpp(280,2):Declaration syntax error
Error:  noname00.cpp(467,1):Declaration missing ;
Error:  noname00.cpp(467,1):Compound statement missing }
```

How can I solve it? I need to run this code in Borland c++ 5.02
Please help me.
link to my code :
http://www10.speedyshare.com/files/26564837/download/mycode.txt

Comment: How do you expect anyone to help if you don't post the actual code ?

Comment: please attach the associated code.

Comment: First of all please read the rules for this site. You ask very, hmm, specific questions, which are generally of no interest to anyone. Now you didn't accept a single answer to your previous question. Finally, SO expects that you try to do something yourself before asking for help. And when you ask, you provide as many *relevant* information as possible, but without overquoting.

Comment: http://www10.speedyshare.com/files/26564837/download/mycode.txt

Comment: please fix and debug my code,and send to me new code

Comment: -1 >>please fix and debug my code,and send to me new code<<   Please come and scrub my toilet, it is filthy.

Comment: :)) no,but ok,please guide me how solve it

Comment: 6 questions, no accepted answer and not enough information to even help you with this...

Comment: possible duplicate of [my code in visual studio 2005 & 2008 & 2010 is work but in borland c++ 5.02 is not work,and have error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838397/my-code-in-visual-studio-2005-2008-2010-is-work-but-in-borland-c-5-02-is-no)

Comment: Damn, you've got -2 (for a reason) for the same question, and now you are reposting it? Do you hope to get more positive response this time? No-go.

Comment: -1 Problem solving starts with you first, tell us what you've done so far and what you have trouble with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void HESAB::variz(int mab,TARIKH date)
{
    x[index].add(mab,amaliat::VARIZenum,date);
    index++;
}

void HESAB::bardasht(int mab,TARIKH date)
{
    x[index].add(mab,amaliat::BARDASHTenum,date);
    index++;
}
```

I think it's complaining about the `amaliat::VARIZenum` syntax. Try specifying just `VARIZenum`.

Comment: wow,very very tnx,solve it,and run in borland :X